# Git repositories often get corrupted on remote server

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04, gitlab

I am facing very serious issue in Gitlab which is making me to think that is Gitlab really reliable for my organization codes.

Gitlab backup (`sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create`) task often get failed reporting that a repository is corrupted. But the thing is **It always reports different project as corrupted**. And trying it several times, the backup will be created successfully.

And then I found, few repositories are corrupted in backup. I just run `git clone --bare bundleName.bundle` for all the repositories. And it reports issue like `Incorrrect data check`, `Incorrect header check` etc.

And If I run `git fsck --all` on server for the very same projects which were coppurted in backup. I found almost projects are fine except a few one.

Then again, I run following script several time for a group named **php** in my Gitlab located at `var/opt/gitlab-git-data/repositories/php`

```
    for dir in php/*git; do (printf "\n\n\n" && echo $dir && cd "$dir" && git fsck --full); done
```

And the problem is **It always tells different projects as corrupted** except one or two project.

Please tell me what causing all this ..? What is the issue ..? How can I get rid of all these...? What's the purpose of backup when It contains corrupted repos.

The server is Ubuntu 14 and Gitlab version is 7.5.3 b656b85 (CE).

I have already run extensive tests on HDD and found not a single issue with it.

**UPDATE 1**

Please Look... there weas 6 repositories (bundles) were corrupted those couldn't not be cloned. I've created a program to clone all repositories from bundles. And when I checked (git fsck --full) the same projects on the server. Everything is fine at this time at least.

[image]